# Where is frontend source file located of azure chat bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I want to make little change in my bot UI.
I dont created a whole UI .Little mark up on UI given by microsoft so want to know

> where is the viewfile/frontend file/htmlfile of azure bot is located
>   in source code ?
>
> currently im using bot with integrating web chat link to .

I have tried finding it in Build>Download bot sourecode 
but i couldnt .

```
  <div id="webchat" role="main" class="sizingSt">
    </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
         window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
               directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                   secret: '*****************************************************'
               }),
            },
            document.getElementById('webchat')
         );
    </script>
```

Comment: So you want to do some customize on your web chat UI right ? If so , this demo may be helpful : https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/21.customization-plain-ui

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're wondering where the "Test in WebChat" code comes from. Basically it comes from [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). There are a [lot of samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list) you can use to integrate this into your bot.

If you need help integrating it:

- We have [a PR for a sample bot that comes with WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1733)
- The WebChat repo also has a good ["How to Use" section](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-use)

If you run into issues, please update your question with what you tried and any relevant code. Then reply to this answer and I can provide additional help.